# Image (GIF) not displaying

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Using colab (python), to visualize a unconfirmed planetary object; this happens! I don't get it! Please help... here is my code
https://colab.research.google.com/github/spacetelescope/notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/MAST/TESS/interm_tesscut_dss_overlay/tesscut_dss_overlay.ipynb#scrollTo=hNBL87NF9Wml&uniqifier=1

CODE with issues:

```
 #display the gif

if not os.path.exists(gif):
    print("No gif found. Cannot display gif of time-series.")

Image(gif, embed=True)
```

### ERROR log:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-27-d599e0c825fd> in <module>()
      2     print("No gif found. Cannot display gif of time-series.")
      3 
----> 4 Image(gif, embed=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/display.py in
__init__(self, data, url, filename, format, embed, width, height, retina, unconfined, metadata)    1013     1014         if self.embed and self.format not in self._ACCEPTABLE_EMBEDDINGS:
-> 1015             raise ValueError("Cannot embed the '%s' image format" % (self.format))    1016         self.width = width    1017    self.height = height

ValueError: Cannot embed the 'gif' image format
```

Comment: Can you disclose which package are you using for Image()

Comment: Could it be that your image has the extension '.gif` but it isn't *actually* a GIF? Check what `file` has to say about it (if you're on a Linux/OS X system), or open the file with a hex viewer and check if its first bytes contain the correct magic signature.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of embedding the filepath:

```
Image(gif, embed=True)
```

you can embed the image bytes directly:

```
Image(open(gif, 'rb').read())
```